# Unable to download BPNM files properly

Tags: html

I has a file with extension .**bpnm**, Follwing is the file i used,

```
 <a id="" href="http://****.bpmn" download>Download BPNM</a>
```

while trying to download that file using **Download BPNM** link,it is showing some xml file in browser.I'm unable to see the actual file. What is wrong here??

I'm using Apache tomcat 6 server
and jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, you can add this to your `.htaccess` file in your web documents folder:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .bpmn
```

Comment: I'm unable to find .htaccess file, could you tell me where is will be?

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't give us details about your webserver. What kind of server do you use? IIS? Apache? Nginx? And do you have support for server-side languages, like PHP etc.?